# Migrate DB2 UDB (Iseries) to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, db2, migration, iseries

I'm looking for a tools that allows migration of DB2/UDB databases to SQL Server. 
It's quite easy migrate schema and data using  linked server or import export with SISS.

But what about stored procedures? We have a lot complex stored procedures. 
There are some tools like the ispirer one -- which is too expensive and not so mature --
other one the swissql one is no more maintained.

What about other tools? Anyone have experience about? My focus is on stored procedure migration.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task to translate from one flavor of SQL to another. That's either (kind of) expensive or difficult to do for yourself.

No database language flavor is really easy to digest and translate into another, because all have lots of system procedures, data types, functions and others that are really system specific.

Each SQL flavor implements a subset of the SQL 92, 99 or 2003 Standard, and then goes further with local features.

Comment: @user1299153 - I'd agree with Marian. As painful as it may be, you might be best off migrating the stored procedures manually to make sure they run appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I can say that Ispirer's product SQLWays not so basic as you say. The tool automatically migrates both data and stored procedures. If you have any doubts, you can try it out by yourself: http://www.ispirer.com/download/download-demo.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SQLines SQL Converter at http://www.sqlines.com/db2-to-sql-server, it supports DDL and stored procedure conversion from DB2 to SQL Server.